# How to modify byte strings?

Tags: python, arrays, byte, elf

Let's say I have the following ELF file in python:

```
>>> data=open('file','rb').read()
>>> data
b'\x7fELF\x02\x01\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00>\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00x\x00@\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00@\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00X\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00@\x008\x00\x01\x00@\x00\x05\x00\x04\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x05\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00@\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00@\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x84\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x84\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00 \x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xbf\x03\x00\x00\x00\xb8<\x00\x00\x00\x0f\x05\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03\x00\x01\x00x\x00@\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x06\x00\x00\x00\x10\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x10\x00\x01\x00\x84\x00`\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\r\x00\x00\x00\x10\x00\x01\x00\x84\x00`\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x14\x00\x00\x00\x10\x00\x01\x00\x88\x00`\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00__bss_start\x00_edata\x00_end\x00\x00.symtab\x00.strtab\x00.shstrtab\x00.text\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x1b\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x06\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00x\x00@\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00x\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x0c\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x88\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x90\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x18\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\t\x00\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x18\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x19\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x11\x00\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x001\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00!\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
```

The first 7 bytes are, in hex:

- `0x7F` `0x45` ("E") `0x4c` ("L") `0x46` ("F") `0x02` `0x01` `0x01`

How would I change the 5th byte to `1` and save the file? Something like:

```
data[5]=1 # gives a 'bytes' assignment error
open('newfile','wb').write(data)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert it to a [`bytearray`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html#func-bytearray), which is a mutable sequence of bytes, for modifying and re-saving the file:

> The bytearray class is a mutable sequence of integers in the range 0 <= x < 256. It has most of the usual methods of mutable sequences, described in Mutable Sequence Types, as well as most methods that the bytes type has

```
# open the file in binary mode and convert to a byte-array
with open('file', 'rb') as f: 
    barray=bytearray(r.read())

# modify the byte in the array
barray[4]=1

# write-out in binary mode
with open('newfile', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(barray)
```